# Combine multiple results as columns, not rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to perform a number of counts on various tables in the database
and I would like to combine those counts into a single result.

Conider the following queries:

```
SELECT 100 As SomeCount
SELECT 200 As SomeOtherCount
SELECT 300 As YetAnotherCount
```

If I combine them using `UNION`, each of the results will be a row in the final result:

```
SELECT 100 As SomeCount
UNION
SELECT 200 As SomeOtherCount
UNION
SELECT 300 As YetAnotherCount
```

Output:

```
> SomeCount
> --------- 
> 100 
> 200 
> 300
```

What I want instead is

```
> SomeCount | SomeOtherCount | YetAnotherCount
> --------------------------------------------
>   100     |      200       |     300
```

The only other way I could think off to 'name' the results is using something like this:

```
SELECT 'SomeCount' As Name, 100 As Value
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SomeOtherCount', 200
UNION ALL
SELECT 'YetAnotherCount', 300
```

In which case the result looks like:

```
>     Name          |      Value
> ---------------------------------
> 'SomeCount'       |       100
> 'SomeOtherCount'  |       200
> 'YetAnotherCount' |       300
```

Is there a way to get the results I want,
or is the last method the way to go?

I should mention the queries above are very simple in order to explain the core problem.
In reality two queries that need to be combined might look like this:

Query 1:

```
SELECT Count(Id) As UndeliveredSms
FROM
(
 SELECT Id
 FROM IncomingSms
 WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT IncomingSmsId
                  FROM DeliveryAttempt
                  WHERE Status = 'Delivered' OR Status = 'FailedPermanently')
 )
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT Count(Id) As UndeliveredEMail FROM
(
 SELECT Id
 FROM IncomingEMail
 WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT IncomingEMailId
                  FROM DeliveryAttempt
                  WHERE Status = 'Delivered' OR Status = 'FailedPermanently')
)
```

Wrapping these in another `SELECT` statement does not work with SQlite.

Using the last method in the examples does work, and I might go
with that solution unless it's a bad idea:

```
SELECT 'UndeliveredSms' As Name,  Count(Id) As Value
FROM
(
 SELECT Id
 FROM IncomingSms
 WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT IncomingSmsId
                  FROM DeliveryAttempt
                  WHERE Status = 'Delivered' OR Status = 'FailedPermanently')
 )

UNION

SELECT 'UndeliveredEMail', Count(Id) FROM
(
 SELECT Id
 FROM IncomingEMail
 WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT IncomingEMailId
                  FROM DeliveryAttempt
                  WHERE Status = 'Delivered' OR Status = 'FailedPermanently')
)
```

Which results in something like this:

```
>     Name           |     Value
> ---------------------------------
> UndeliveredEMail   |       82
> UndeliveredSms     |       0
```

And of course, in reality, there are a lot more things to count

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use a CROSS JOIN between the queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT Count(Id) As UndeliveredSms
  FROM
  (
   SELECT Id
   FROM IncomingSms
   WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT IncomingSmsId
                    FROM DeliveryAttempt
                    WHERE Status = 'Delivered' OR Status = 'FailedPermanently')
  )
)
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT Count(Id) As UndeliveredEMail FROM
  (
   SELECT Id
   FROM IncomingEMail
   WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT IncomingEMailId
                    FROM DeliveryAttempt
                    WHERE Status = 'Delivered' OR Status = 'FailedPermanently')
  )
);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f8ac1/3)

Comment: Is the Union necessary in this case?  Appears to work without given the nature of the two queries: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f8ac1/6

Comment: @user2480596 That is up to the OP.  My sample data didn't include any items that met the criteria of the second part of the UNION and I guessed on the table structure.  I assume they need that for their final result.

Comment: Yes, the UNION is required to include items for which no DeliveryAttempt has yet been made. In essence, give me all emails with the status delivered or failed permanently or for which no attempt has been made.

Comment: Actually come to think about it @user2480596 it might not be required let me rethink it, I think I might have been trying to do something else at first, nice catch thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand the use of the `UNION` in your queries, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding.  Not in a subset union not in all = not in a subset...

Seems like it can be simplified to the following:

```
select *
from
(
  SELECT Count(Id) As UndeliveredSms
  FROM IncomingSms
  WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT IncomingSmsId
                    FROM DeliveryAttempt
                    WHERE Status = 'Delivered' OR Status = 'FailedPermanently')
) t, 
(
  SELECT Count(Id) As UndeliveredEMail 
  FROM IncomingEMail
  WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT IncomingEMailId
                    FROM DeliveryAttempt
                    WHERE Status = 'Delivered' OR Status = 'FailedPermanently')
  ) t2
```

Comment: Actually you might be right, I must have been trying to solve it differently before. I'll look into it, nice catch!

Comment: @TimothyP --  np -- hope this helped.  Bluefeet provided the correct answer -- this was just a side note :) Cheers!