# How to collapse similar rows in SQL query

Tags: sql

Using an MS SQL query, I would like to collapse redundant data in sequential rows to make a report easier to read. Suppose I have the following data:

```
ID | Department | Name  | Task
-------------------------------------------------
1    Sales        Mike    Call customer
2    Sales        Mike    Create quote
3    Sales        Sarah   Create order
4    Engineering  Sam     Design prototype
5    Engineering  Sam     Calculate loads
6    Production   Team1   Build parts
7    Production   Team2   Build parts
8    Production   Team1   Assemble parts
9    Accounting   Amy     Invoice job
10   Sales        Mike    Call customer
11   Sales        Mike    Follow up after 30 days
```

How can I get the following summarized rows from my query:

```
Sales: Mike (Call customer, Create quote) Sarah (Create order)
Engineering: Sam (Design prototype, Calculate loads)
Production: Team1 (Build parts) Team2 (Build parts) Team1 (Assemble parts)
Accounting: Amy (Invoice job)
Sales: Mike (Call customer, Follow up after 30 days)
```

Essentially if the previous department and name are the same, add the task to a comma separated sub-list. If only the department is the same, start a new named sub-list and if the department is new then start a new row. Notice that items 10 and 11 should not be included in the first row so that the order of tasks is not lost.

In C# this task is easy using loops and/or Linq, however, I now need to produce the same result from a SQL query.

Comment: try to use `group by`

Comment: @Girly Girl: What should I group by, and how would I keep rows 10 and 11 from grouping with rows 1-3?

Comment: As @Girly Girl mentioned, `GROUP BY` is usually used to combine rows, but not 'keep values from each' as in your case. Have a search on SE for other answers about combining multiple rows - but you will want the more complex ones where you are combining the data from those rows into one column. Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667599/combine-multiple-results-as-columns-not-rows

The other difficulty you have is deciding which rows to combine, but it seems that you have already recognized that. It looks like `ID` is the only way to do this.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: Also, since this is going to get tricky, and probably implementation-specific, you should tell us which dialect of SQL (eg MS SQL Server 2008) you are using.

Comment: Why are you doing this in SQL?  This smells like a presentation layer requirement.

Comment: I'm using MS SQL 2008 R2. The reason for doing this at the database level is to ensure consistent results between the UI and various SSRS and HTML reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursive Common Table Expressions ([working SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e4214/1))

```
;with RecursivePersonTask( Id, Department, Name, Tasks )
as
( 
  select
   a.Id
   , a.Department
   , a.Name
   , a.Task    
  from
   dbo.Task a
   left outer join dbo.Task b
    on a.Department = b.Department
       and a.Name = b.Name
       and a.Id = b.Id + 1
  where
   b.Id is null

  union all

  select
   t.Id
   , t.Department
   , t.Name
   , rpt.Tasks + ', ' + t.Task
  from
   RecursivePersonTask rpt
   inner join dbo.Task t
    on rpt.Department = t.Department
       and rpt.Name = t.Name
       and rpt.Id = t.Id - 1
)
, CombinedPersonTasks( Id, Department, Name, Tasks )
as
(
  select 
   ROW_NUMBER() over ( order by a.Id )
   , a.Department
   , a.Name
   , '(' + a.Tasks + ')'
  from 
   RecursivePersonTask a
   left outer join RecursivePersonTask b
    on a.Department = b.Department
       and a.Name = b.Name
       and a.Id = b.Id - 1
  where
   b.Id is null
)
, RecursiveDepartmentTasks( Id, Department, Tasks )
as
( 
  select
   a.Id
   , a.Department
   , a.Name + ' ' + a.Tasks
  from
   CombinedPersonTasks a
   left outer join CombinedPersonTasks b
    on a.Department = b.Department
       and a.Id = b.Id + 1
  where
   b.Id is null

  union all

  select
   cpt.Id
   , cpt.Department
   , rdt.Tasks + ' ' + cpt.Name + ' ' + cpt.Tasks
  from
   RecursiveDepartmentTasks rdt
   inner join CombinedPersonTasks cpt
    on rdt.Department = cpt.Department
       and rdt.Id = cpt.Id - 1
)
, CombinedDepartmentTasks( Id, Department, Tasks )
as
(
  select 
   ROW_NUMBER() over ( order by a.Id )
   , a.Department
   , a.Tasks
  from 
   RecursiveDepartmentTasks a
   left outer join RecursiveDepartmentTasks b
    on a.Department = b.Department
       and a.Id = b.Id - 1
  where
   b.Id is null
)

select 
 * 
from
 CombinedDepartmentTasks 
order by 
 Id
```

Comment: This provides the exact output I'm after so I'm accepting it as the answer, even though I will not have a chance to test against my database for a few days.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQL Server 2012, you can use the ROWS parameters of the windowing functions:

```
with tasks as (
select 1 as id, 'Sales' as dept ,'Mike' as name, 'Call customer' as task union
select 2, 'Sales' ,'Mike', 'Create quote' union
select  3, 'Sales' ,'Sarah', '   Create order' union
select 4, 'Engineering' ,'Sam', '     Design prototype' union
select 5, 'Engineering' ,'Sam', '     Calculate loads' union
select 6, 'Production' ,'Team1', '   Build parts' union
select 7, 'Production' ,'Team2', '   Build parts' union
select 8, 'Production' ,'Team1', '   Assemble parts' union
select 9, 'Accounting' ,'Amy', '     Invoice job' union
select 10, 'Sales' ,'Mike', '    Call customer' union
select 11, 'Sales' ,'Mike', '    Follow up after 30 days' 
)

select max(NewDepartmentRollover) over (order by id rows unbounded preceding) as ColumnToGroupOn , * from (

select 
case when max(dept) over (order by id rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) = dept then NULL else id end as NewDepartmentRollover,
*  from tasks
) GroupOn
```

If you only have SQL Server 2005 or 2008, something like this will do:

```
with tasks as (
select 1 as id, 'Sales' as dept ,'Mike' as name, 'Call customer' as task union
select 2, 'Sales' ,'Mike', 'Create quote' union
select  3, 'Sales' ,'Sarah', '   Create order' union
select 4, 'Engineering' ,'Sam', '     Design prototype' union
select 5, 'Engineering' ,'Sam', '     Calculate loads' union
select 6, 'Production' ,'Team1', '   Build parts' union
select 7, 'Production' ,'Team2', '   Build parts' union
select 8, 'Production' ,'Team1', '   Assemble parts' union
select 9, 'Accounting' ,'Amy', '     Invoice job' union
select 10, 'Sales' ,'Mike', '    Call customer' union
select 11, 'Sales' ,'Mike', '    Follow up after 30 days' 
)


, b  as (
select 
row_number() over (order by tasks.id) as rn,
 tasks.id as lefty
from tasks
left join tasks t3
on t3.id = tasks.id - 1
where tasks.dept <> isnull(t3.dept,'')
)

select tasks.*, lefty as columnToGroupOn from tasks left join (

select b.lefty, isnull(b2.lefty,999)-1 as righty from b
left join 
b  b2 on b.rn = b2.rn - 1
) c
on tasks.id between lefty and righty
```

Comment: Will these query concatenate the strings?

Comment: +1 for an answer that works in MS SQL as requested; however, this only gets me part way there so I'm accepting @Moho's answer.